# Transpiling third-party modules with create-react-app build

Tags: reactjs, module, webpack, create-react-app

I'm developing a recently-ejected [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) application and need to use an outside [module](https://github.com/jonbri/starparam).

I did `npm install --save-dev starparam` and am importing the module like this: `import starparam from 'starparam';`.

When I run my code in NodeJS with my unit-tests (`npm test`) everything works as expected.

But, when I run in the browser (using `npm start`) I get syntax errors.

This seems to be because the module I'm using [uses ES6 features](https://github.com/jonbri/starparam/blob/master/index.js#L16) like arrow functions.

What webpack changes do I need to make so this third-party module is included in the transpile?

Comment: Usually `node_modules` is excluded in the `webpack.config.js`, you could change it like in this ticket. https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/171

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running `node_modules` through Babel. It's not always safe (things can break) and makes builds significantly slower.

Comment: I was able to accomplish my goal by adding a loader in my webpack config but I'm not quite clear if my approach is following a good practice. I added an answer describing what I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814538/2295034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my goal by:

- **adding a new path** in `config/paths.js` to the third-party module folder
- **adding a new loader** in the `loaders` array in the `module` object in `config/webpack.config.dev.js`
- a similar change in `config/webpack.config.prod.js`

--

Adding a new path in `config/paths.js`;

```
starparamSrc: resolveApp('node_modules/starparam'),
```

Adding a new loader in `config/webpack.config.dev.js`:

```
{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  include: paths.starparamSrc,
  loader: 'babel',
  query: {
   cacheDirectory: true
  }
},
```